# Is there any free word-frequency dictionary?

Tags: word-usage, dictionaries, frequency

Sometimes, despite I can see the meaning of a word in a dictionary, I don't know which variation of a word has the most application?

For example, I find the word `loathed` in a text and I find it in an online dictionary. But I wonder if `loathe` has the same number of applications in modern English?

Is there any application or online website which provides such a search? Ideally, I look for a database which analyses millions of text and counts the frequency application of each word you search (giving you a number).

I need it to prevent using a word which native usually avoid; despite it is grammatically and semantically correct.

Comment: Mere frequency does not indicate aptness to context. The word less used may be the right word.

Comment: Please wait a day or two before accepting an answer. For why this is wise, see [here](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1307/6700).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a request for resources.

Comment: @Chenmunka, And I request admins to stop people who destroy good questions which benefit others.

Comment: For your last sentence, I hate to say it, but the only true way to know which words to avoid, is to live in a location and adapt your speech to what is heard.  For my Japanese study, I have been rightfully told "If you have not heard a Japanese person say it, it is not correct."  More so because local dialects will vary as well.  Words used in one part of America are funny in others.  Same fore British/American/Australian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be looking for the *Corpus of Contemporary American English* (COCA) which is said to be the largest corpus of American English currently available.

> The corpus contains more than 520 million words of text (20 million words each year 1990-2015) and it is equally divided among spoken, fiction, popular magazines, newspapers, and academic texts.

Link [to COCA](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/)